# PHP problem with mixing __get and __set call

Tags: php

I have a problem when mixing the use of __get and __set method

```
class TestClass {}

$obj = new TestClass();
var_dump($obj->test); //throw notice as expected
$obj->invalidprop['key'] = 'test';

var_dump($obj->invalidprop);
//=> array('key' => 'test')
```

The native behavior works perfectly by populating the dynamic property with an array with value, with zero warning/notice.

But as soon I add a __get and __set to add some functionality, I am unable to reproduce the default behavior.

```
class TestClass {
    public function &__get($prop) {
        if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $prop)) {
             $func = 'get' . $prop;
             return $this->$func();
        }

        //else throw default notice warning
        trigger_error('Undefined property ... ');
    }

    public function __set($prop, $value) {
        $this->$prop = $value;
    }
}
```

So I run `$obj->invalidprop['key'] = 'test';` again, which trigger `__get`  when accessing `invalidprop` and at the same time `__set` because it's assigning a value. Not only it throws the custom trigger_error I defined, but it also doesn't populate an array as expected.

Question: how to reproduce native behavior (with 0 notice warning) while keeping the same additional functionality in the __get() ?

Comment: It does not call `_set()`. And its your code that triggers the error because the method `getinvalidprop` does not exist.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replicate? Since you're creating the props dynamically (like you're doing in your `__set()`-method), they will be public by default. When you then try and get a prop (which was added added using `__set()`), it will just fetch the property directly instead of using the `__get()` method. `__get()` and `__set()` are only invoked for non-existing and protected/private properties.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know perfectly why they are triggered. But my question still stand : how to replicate "the default behavior", by populating the array( key => test ) correctly. Because after defining `__get` it just stops working

Answer (score 1):

this way it works fine:

```
<?php

class TestClass {

    public function &__get($prop) {
        echo "Get Prop: $prop\n";

        if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $prop)) {
             $func = 'get' . $prop;
             return $this->$func();
        }

        //else throw default notice warning
        trigger_error('Undefined property ... ');
    }

    public function __set($prop, $value) {

        echo "Set Prop: $prop\n";
        $this->$prop = $value;
    }
}

$obj = new TestClass;

$obj->invalidprop = ['key' => 'test'];
var_dump($obj->invalidprop);
```

Comment: While this would work, this requires the modification of the original code and cannot replicate the native behavior of php. I would simply put `$obj->invalidprop = []; $obj->invalidprop['key'] = 'test';` to initiate the value. But of course, I must do it everywhere is the whole web application. Could we find a better way?

Comment: @ThanhTrung By using PHP's magic methods like `__get()` or `__set()` I would say no, or actually there is one - do not use them at all. Just make every property of class you want to be accessible from outside having its own setter/getter method. Because using magic methods like you did is a bad practice. For example if you had a private property `$secretKey` inside your class then it will be no secret because your magic method `__set()` and `__get()` will provide access to it. Also debugging of any problem is much harder when you have magic methods.

Comment: @ThanhTrung If you want to make your coding faster and don't like to write getters and setters for every property then look at something like [PHP Getters & Setters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=phproberto.vscode-php-getters-setters) that can easily do it for you.

Comment: This is not a matter of exposing the private props. I simply create a functionnality called "virtual property" like any other php framework does : https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-getset-methods#getters-and-setters-in-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only variable as ref, not function result. In `$obj->invalidprop['key'] = 'test';` there is no any "set" - only "get" and modify value by reference.

Example

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    private $props = [];
    public function &__get($a) {
        if (!array_key_exists($a, $this->props)) {
            $this->props[$a] = [];
        }
        $a = &$this->props[$a];
        return $a;
    }
}
$obj = new TestClass();
$obj->invalidprop['key'] = 'test';
var_dump($obj->invalidprop);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

Comment: Is creating `private $props = [];` a requirement? Would you be able to modify my code exemple and adapt it to work? If you call the prop for the 2nd time, it will say that the value is an array instead of throwing a notice that the prop doesn't exist